# Unable to print the properties from same class in c#

Tags: c#, properties

Write a C# program that gets a person's date of birth as input   and calculates his/her age and display the age. The program should also check whether the person is an adult or child.
Display the results as given in the sample output.
Create a class called Person.
Create fields, properties and method as given below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpK5R.png)

Create objects for person  from a class called Program that contains the Main method and display the details from the DisplayDetails method.

Note:

Don't create new namespaces.

Create classes with pubic access specifier.

Follow the naming conventions strictly.

Sample input : 1

Enter first name

Alice

Enter last name

Moses

Enter date of birth in yyyy/mm/dd/ format

1998/12/23

Sample Output : 1

First Name: Alice

Last Name: Moses

Age: 19

Adult

Sample input : 2

Enter first name

Joe

Enter last name

Noel

Enter date of birth in yyyy/mm/dd/ format

2002/10/15

Sample Output : 2

First Name: Alice

Last Name: Moses

Age: 17

Child

When I am trying to run the below code it is not printing the stages i.e Adult or child, I do not understand what I am doing wrong here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace C_SHARP
{
    public class Person
    {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private DateTime dob;
        private String stages;
        public String FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                firstName = value;
            }
        }
        public String LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                lastName = value;
            }
        }
        public DateTime Dob
        {
            get
            {
                return dob;
            }
            set
            {
                dob = value;
            }

        }
        public String Adult
        {
            get
            {
                return stages;
            }
            set
            {
                if (GetAge(dob) > 18)
                {
                    stages = "Adult";
                }
                else
                {
                    stages = "Child";
                }
            }
        }
        public void DisplayDetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + this.firstName);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + this.lastName);
            Console.WriteLine("Age: "+this.GetAge(dob));
            Console.WriteLine(this.stages);
        }
        public int GetAge(DateTime dob)
        {
            int age = 0;
            age = DateTime.Now.Year - dob.Year;
            return age;
        }
    }

    public class Progarm
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Person obj = new Person();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first name");
            obj.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter last name");
            obj.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter date of birth in yyyy/mm/dd/ format");
            obj.Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
            obj.DisplayDetails();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never set `stages`. The only place I see it getting set is in the setter for `Adult`, which is never called. Perhaps you meant to put that code in the setter for `Dob`?

Comment: I just wanted to compare the age with 18 in Adult property but I do not understand how to use age in the set method of Adult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some other issues in here as the Date comparing only on year is not accurate and leads to rounding the age to the year. That aside you can get what you have printing correctly by making a small change.

You can set the Adult value to "" or String.Empty which will result in your setter logic being executed. This will then provide the stages variable with a value that you can print to the Console.

```
            obj.Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
            obj.Adult = String.Empty;
            obj.DisplayDetails();
```

Result for your sample data:
[image: Alice Moses Age 23 Adult]

Comment: Yes this one is working fine but on implementing this logic it is saying that.  Fail 1 :   The Adult property has not been implemented as per the requirement

Comment: Ah gotcha. Making some changes. Looks like you may have to handle it in the Setter to meet your requirements.

Comment: If you can give the latest a try and see if that meets your requirement.

Comment: Yes it is working fine now and it is passing all the cases and we need to change the code in Adult property also that I have already done you can check the below code. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the 'stages' field.

Comment: Yes but there are two possibilities for that i.e "Adult" or "Child" that's why I am confused how to set these values inside the set method of Adult

Comment: I don't really know how C# works, but maybe make a CheckStage method with the same code as in 'Adult.set', and then call it at the end of 'Dob.set'

Answer (score 0):

This one is working fine now and it is passing 100% test cases.

```
public String Adult
    {
        get
        {
            if (GetAge(dob) >= 18)
            {
                return "Adult";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Child";
            }
        }
        set
        {}  
    }
```

And for the main class I have used an empty string to assign value to the Adult property.

```
obj.Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
        obj.Adult = "";
        obj.DisplayDetails();
```

[Ouput Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR47L.jpg)